# Какие неисследованные и спорные вопросы есть в русском языке?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Слышал, подобное есть о роли в предложении слов "минус"/"плюс", точнее о их принадлежности к той или иной части речи. Не хочу затрагивать вопрос о том, чем же они являются, а именно интересуюсь, что сегодня является неоднозначным, неизученным и гипотетическим в русском языке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Практически вся грамматика (синтаксис, морфология)спорна. Почитайте материалы форума! Здесь и причастие с деепричастием (их место в системе частей речи), и категория состояния (отдельная часть речи или нет?), местоименные наречия, границы сказуемого, типы сказуемых, односоставные... А уж более частных вопросов, по которым спорили и продолжают спорить, не  счесть...

Answer (score 0):

В номинативных предложениях главный член – подлежащее или сказуемое?

Answer (score 0):

[[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f), много плюсов.
Можно проще сказать:  **"Все!"**.
Вообще ставить вопрос о том, что неиследованно в заведомо бесконечно (да еще постоянно меняющейся!) системе - некорректно. 
Вот если ограничиться конечным подмножеством. Скажем, правописанием. Или имеющимися моделями грамматики...